# LNK4217 warning on a class derived from an abstract DLL interface class

Tags: c++

I am getting a LNK4217 warning when compiling two classes: One is defining an abstract interface and a static factory method that will return an object that implements this interface. This class is exported via `__declspec(dllexport)`. The other class implements the interface. Here's a reduced example that reproduces the warning:

PublicAPI.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#ifdef PublicAPI_Exports
#define API_EXP __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define API_EXP __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

class API_EXP PublicAPI
{
public:
  virtual ~PublicAPI();

  static std::shared_ptr<PublicAPI> init(const char *selection);

  virtual int compute() = 0;

protected:
  PublicAPI();
};
```

PublicAPI.cpp

```
#include "PublicAPI.h"
#include "../PrivateAPI/PrivateAPI.h"

PublicAPI::PublicAPI() {}

PublicAPI::~PublicAPI() {}

std::shared_ptr<PublicAPI> PublicAPI::init(const char *selection)
{
  return std::make_shared<PrivateAPI>(selection);
}
```

PrivateAPI.h

```
#pragma once

#include "../PublicAPI/PublicAPI.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class PrivateAPI : public PublicAPI
{
public:
  PrivateAPI(std::string selection);
  virtual ~PrivateAPI();

  virtual int compute();

private:
  PrivateAPI();
  // should have more private members here, avoided to shorten the example
};
```

PrivateAPI.cpp

```
#include "PrivateAPI.h"

PrivateAPI::PrivateAPI() {}

PrivateAPI::PrivateAPI(std::string selection)
{
  // init members based on selection
}

PrivateAPI::~PrivateAPI() {}

int PrivateAPI::compute()
{
  return 42;
}
```

The `PrivateAPI` is compiled into a static lib, the `PublicAPI` into a DLL and links against `PrivateAPI`. `PublicAPI_Exports` is defined in the `PublicAPI` project.

The warnings I am getting are:

```
3>PrivateAPI.lib(PrivateAPI.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1PublicAPI@@UEAA@XZ (public: virtual __cdecl PublicAPI::~PublicAPI(void)) imported in function "public: virtual __cdecl PrivateAPI::~PrivateAPI(void)" (??1PrivateAPI@@UEAA@XZ)
3>PrivateAPI.lib(PrivateAPI.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0PublicAPI@@IEAA@XZ (protected: __cdecl PublicAPI::PublicAPI(void)) imported in function "private: __cdecl PrivateAPI::PrivateAPI(void)" (??0PrivateAPI@@AEAA@XZ)
```

I read through the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4217?view=vs-2017) and StackOverflow regarding this linker warning, but I still don't get what's exactly wrong here, or how to properly fix it :/

Comment: You forgot to define the PublicAPI_Exports macro in the project that builds the DLL.  So the linker sees *two* definitions, one that's dllimport and another in the .cpp file.  That's an ODR violation.  Right-click the project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > "Preprocessor Definitions" setting.  Add PublicAPI_Exports.

Comment: @HansPassant The PublicAPI_Exports is defined in the PublicAPI project (as mentioned above) - I just double checked.

Comment: That's not what the linker says.  Make sure it is defined for all configurations and all platforms.  And keep in mind that it can easily be overlooked for a static library that you link.

Comment: OK, additionally defining the PublicAPI_Exports macro in the PrivateAPI project resolves the warning. Just to make sure I am getting the reasoning behind this right: PrivateAPI is including the PublicAPI header to define a class inheriting from PublicAPI. So at the time PrivateAPI is compiled into a static lib we must make sure that the dllexport is defined in the PublicAPI header, because later the PublicAPI (which also defines the dllexport) is linking against the PrivateAPI static lib and the export definitions have to match!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out two solutions:

**Solution 1** (courtesy of @HansPassant and imho the better/more generic solution)

The `PublicAPI_Exports` needs to be defined also for the `PrivateAPI` project, not only for the `PublicAPI` project.

My understanding as to why: The `PrivateAPI` class is inheriting from `PublicAPI`, hence it is also including the `PublicAPI.h`. The `PrivateAPI` is also "inheriting" the dllimport/dllexport definition from `PublicAPI`. However, the `PrivateAPI` is compiled independently into a static lib and later only linked by `PublicAPI`. So when `PrivateAPI` is compiled *without* `PublicAPI_Exports` being defined, the `PrivateAPI` class will be defined as `dllimport` (via `PublicAPI.h`). When the `PublicAPI` project is build *with* `PublicAPI_Exports` being defined and then linked against the `PrivateAPI` static lib, these definitions don't match and cause this warning. So defining `PublicAPI_Exports` for both, the `PublicAPI` and the `PrivateAPI` projects, is necessary.

**Solution 2** (for my particular example)

It seems I can also only `dllexport` the static `init` function which creates an object that fulfills the `PublicAPI` interface. This requires to change the `PublicAPI.h` as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#ifdef PublicAPI_Exports
#define API_EXP __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define API_EXP __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

class PublicAPI
{
public:
  virtual ~PublicAPI();

  API_EXP static std::shared_ptr<PublicAPI> init(const char *selection);

  virtual int compute() = 0;

protected:
  PublicAPI();
};
```

This works, because the static function is not declared again in the `PrivateAPI`. The object returned by `init` seems to work just fine (i.e. the `compute` function is accessible) in a client including and linking the `PublicAPI`.